# How can you make a regexp in MOD-REWRITE optional?

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, translation, optional-parameters

I need to add a translation service to the job listings section of my site to make the content available in multiple languages.

Right now, I'm using mod rewrite to make the following pretty URL:

/jobs/JobLocation/JobOpening/

Using this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([A-Za-z_-]+)$ /jobs/$1/$2/ [R]
RewriteRule ^jobs/([A-Za-z_-]+)/([A-Za-z_-]+)/$ /listing.php?location=$1&job=$2
```

I would like to optionally be able to add a language attribute to the beginning of this URL (and others on my site), so that I can translate the page. I would like the regular URL above to work for the default language (english), but I'd like the following to work as well:

/jobs/es/JobLocation/JobOpening/

I believe I can do this by adding an optional part to my mod rewrite regexp, but I'm not sure what the correct syntax is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way as every other regex syntax: a question mark (`?`).

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/(([A-Za-z_-]{2,3})/)?([A-Za-z_-]+)/([A-Za-z_-]+)/$ /listing.php?location=$3&job=$4&lang=$2
```

Comment: How can I refer to this with a backreference if it will not always be present?